# Preparing update command using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a output file that contains 3 different column data-

```
          ['AARF'],SAMPLE12,2016-01-05 12:00:00-0500
                  ,529OFFST,2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400
          "['EPROSP_IWS', '648099_EPROSP_IWS']",4.NDR-IWS-EPRO,2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400
```

I tried with below sed command-

```
        sed -i "s/\(\"*\[[^]]*\]\"*\)\(.*\)/{\1:\"\"}\2/" tempFile
        sed "s/' *, *'/' '/g;s/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/update table set cross_refs = \1 where id = \2 and effective_date = \3/;s/' '/','/g" tempFile > updatestmt.cql
        sed -i "s/$/';/" updatestmt.cql
```

My Expected o/p-

```
       update table set cross_refs ={'AARF':''}  where id = 'SAMPLE12' and effective_date = '2016-01-05 12:00:00-0500';
       update table set cross_refs = {'':''} where id = '529OFFST' and effective_date = '22016-01-05 12:00:00-0500';
       update table set cross_refs = {'EPROSP_IWS':'','648099_EPROSP_IWS':''} where id = '4.NDR-IWS-EPRO' and effective_date = '2015-04-16 08:04:21-0400';
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Does this have to be `sed`?

Comment: @cdarke- actually am parsing the string using sed. but didnt get the expected output. Can you please suggest me on this?

Comment: I just updated my expected output result. can somebody help me out

Answer (score 3):

Not in `sed` but comma separated data equals asking for `awk` to me :)

```
#!awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }  # split fields on comma
{
    gsub(/[\]\[\"]/,"")  # remove useless chars: [,],"
    i=1
    crefs="{"
    while (i <= (NF-2)) {  # loop from first to 3rd last field
        tmp = $(i) ? $(i) : "''"  # if no value, add empty quotes
        crefs=crefs""tmp":'',"  # append current field value or empty to crefs
        i++
    }
    sub(/,$/, "", crefs)  # remove trailing comma
    crefs=crefs"}"
    print "update table set cross_refs ="crefs" where id='"$(NF-1)"' and effective_date ='"$(NF)"'"
}
```